# put a mouseover on text display image in div in java script

Tags: image, mouseover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

     function show1() {
            document.getElementById("img1").display = 'block';
     }
     function hide1() {
            document.getElementById("img1").display = 'none';
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.feverpitchholidays.com/corporate-team-outing-lnt/"><span onMouseOver="show1()" onMouseOut="hide1()">Corporate Team Outing - LNT</span></a>

<div id="img1" style="display:none">
    <img src="" alt="image 1" />
    <img src="" alt="image 2" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want that when u put mouse on text it show image in div i m trying to do it but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Forget javascript for this one! CSS is the answer. Put a hover state on ID:img1 and the images inside the div (if u don't do the latter, mousing over the images will cancel out the div mouse over. So it will look like this (not inline styles due to mouse over states declaration):

```
#img1 {
  Background-image: none;
}

#img1:hover, img1:hover img {
  Background-image: url(your URL);
}
```

You could change the IDs to classes, so the CSS can be reused and keep the IDs for coding (javascript etc)

Comment: But i want to use with java script its a requirement so kindly help me in java script code

Comment: actually i looking in java script so plz tell me java script how i will do it.